# Is the Samsung Camera SDK used to expand on the Camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-camera2, samsung-mobile-sdk

Should I use the Camera2 API to do the basic functions of a camera (take picture, video), and use the SCamera SDK to supplement those features (HDR, low light, etc.)?

I'm developing for a Galaxy S6, and S5 only.

Comment: Samsung Camera SDK mimics official Camera2 API so you should be able to implement all features you need using only Samsung Camera SDK. If you aim only S6 and S5 devices I think that you can safely use Samsung SDK only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [Samsung Camera SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera), because I had several troubles on Samsung devices, by using the standard Android Camera 2 API. Which includes the:

- Focus Area
- Metering Area

This video describes best, what are the main benefits by using the Samsung Camera SDK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEruxA3i5Ok

**!The SDK requires Android 5.0 Lollipop!**